# Exporting Three JS with blender gives me errors...(Linux ubuntu)

Tags: three.js, export, blender

I made a model with blender. I exported with three.js. I got some errors. I am using a linux ubuntu. I am using blender 2.62(I think). When I export, this is what shows up:

```
! Error
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs/__init__.py" line 340, in execute 
    return io_mesh_threejs.export_threejs.save(self, context, **self.properties

 File "/usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs/export_threejs.py" line 2697, in save
    option_frame_index_as_time)

 File "/usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs/export_threejs.py" line 1776, in export mesh
    option_frame_step)

 File "/usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs/export_threejs.py" line 1661, in generate_mesh_string
    meshes = extract_meshes(objects, scene, export_single_model, option_scale, flipyz)

 File "File "/usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs/export_threejs.py" line 1631, in extracted_meshes
    mesh.update(calc_tessface=true)

 TypeError: Mesh.Update(): was called with invalid keyword argument(s) (calc_tessface), expected (calc_edges)

 location:<unknown location>:-1
```

Anyone know a way to fix this? Do I go into export_threejs.py and change calc_tessface to calc_edges?? What do I do? I don't want to mess anything up.